# GetText 0 pluralisation

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I genuinely can't find any results anywhere on this. But basically what I'm looking for is the ability to be able to show a different message in PHP Gettext based on whether or not the count is 0, 1, or obviously a plural. I'm developing a read time for an article, so the strings should be soomething like:

```
Less than 1 min
1 min
2 mins
3 mins .....
```

At the moment I have it working with plurals, but I just don't know whether it's possible what I'm trying to do or whether I need to have seperate strings for the 0 value.

This is my current code:

```
# Article read time
msgid "Less than 1 min"
msgstr "Less than 1 min"

msgid "%num% min"
msgid_plural "%num% mins"
msgstr[0] "%num% min"
msgstr[1] "%num% mins"
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Every po file should contain a line `Plural-Forms` in the po header.  For example for English or German it reads like this:

```
Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);
```

The syntax for this line is a small subset of C (or most C-style languages). It has three variables:

- `nplurals`: the number of plural forms
- `n`: the number of items to retrieve a plural form for
- `plural`: the computed index of the plural form

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Translating-plural-forms.html for more information!

You could simply increase `nplurals` in that formula, for example for English:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Plural-Form: nplurals=3; plural = n ? n > 1 ? 1 : 0 : 2;
```

Now you have three "plural" forms. Form 0 would still be the grammatical singular, form 1 the grammatical plural, and 2 the new form for zero items.

Some notes:

1. This is a good question. While most languages don't have a formal grammatical number for zero items, categorizing it as either plural (English, German, ...) or singular (French, ...) often sounds awkward because to most people "no files" sounds better and more natural than "0 files".
2. You have to explain that feature to your translators, in doubt by translator comments above the strings.
3. You should give the artifical grammatical number for zero items the highest index. If a `.po` file is not modified for the feature, it will just fall back to the old behavior.
4. You need a `po` file for English resp. your primary language because you will not be able to code your new logic into the source code as the `ngettext` function only has 3 arguments.

An example (in C because I don't know PHP good enough):

```
printf(ngettext("one item", "%d items", num_items), num_items);
```

This would result in this entry in your `en.po` file:

```
msgid "one item"
msgid_plural "%d items"
msgstr[0] "one item"
msgstr[1] "%d items"
msgstr[2] "no items"
```

Note that you have no possibility to have the string "no items" in the `ngettext()` invocation of your source file.

If you want to make that solution work even without an English `.po` file, you could provide your own version of `ngettext()`, for example `ngettext0()` with an implementation like this:

```
const char *
ngettext0(const char *sg, const char *pl, const char *zero, count)
{
        if (count) {
            /* Default behavior.  */
            return ngettext(sg, pl, count);
        } else {
            /* For a count of 0, use the provided "zero" argument as
               the fallback translation.  */
            return ngettext(sg, zero, 0);
        }
}
```

This uses the fact that - if no translation exists - the `ngettext()` function will use the singular argument for one item, and the plural argument for everything else (including 0) because it hard-codes the English plural rules.

If you go with that wrapper around `ngettext()` you must also change the invocation of `xgettext` in your build system:

```
xgettext ... --keyword=ngettext0:1,2
```

This would extract the first argument to `ngettext0` as the singular, and the second one as the plural. Note! There is no way to tell `xgettext` to extract a third argument.

Depending on your programming language, you may also need `flag` options:

```
xgettext ... --keyword=ngettext0:1,2 --flag=ngettext0:1:pass-c-format --flag=ngettext0:2:pass-c-format
```

Decide yourself whether this is worth all the hassle. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't need to worry about handling plurals if you use gettext, it will handle it by design.

For your question, use the following snippet:

```php
$n = 0;
printf(ngettext('%u min', '%u mins', $n), $n)
```

When run in English locale, it will display `0 mins`, when in french locale -- `0 min`, which corresponds exactly to the grammar of corresponding languages